# Laravel 5.2 Trying to get property of non-object when getting data from database

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i m working with laravel 5.2 i have 2 Models

Prof :

```
  class Prof extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=array('nom','prenom','age','mail');

public function matieres(){

    return $this->hasMany(Matiere::class,'id_prof');
}
}
```

Matiere :

```
class Matiere extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=array('Nom');

public function profs(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(Prof::class,'id_prof');
    }
}
```

in MatiereController i have the methode that gives me all Matieres:

```
public function index()
    {
        $matiere = Matiere::all();
        return view('Matiere.index',compact('matiere'));
    }
```

in my view i show the list of my Matiere and the name of the prof that teach this subject (Matiere) using

```
 @foreach ($matiere as $mat)
      @foreach ($mat->profs as $pr)
       {{$pr->prenom}}
      @endforeach                
   @endforeach
```

But i get this error

**Trying to get property of non-object**

How could i fix this ? thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to specify the foreign key in the hasMany and BelongsTo, It's kind of magic but normally Eloquent is able to understand and search the right id from the foreign key (If you created the foreign relations in the migration's file).

Second, when you do the foreach in your blade code, you call `$mat->profs` which returns if I'm not wrong a Collection or array instead of returning an array of Objects. So that's why you get an error of trying to get a property of a non object.

So to fix that you need to do the following

```
@foreach ($matiere as $mat)
    @foreach ($mat->profs() as $pr)
        {{$pr->prenom}}
    @endforeach                
@endforeach
```

If you call the method `profs()` on the `$mat` object then it returns an array of objects.

Bonne chance pour la suite ;)

Comment: Thnk u so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by using only one foreach

```
@foreach ($matiere as $mat)
      {{ $mat->profs->prenom}}               
@endforeach
```